# Failed to connect to www.googleapis.com port 443: and some CURL information needed

Tags: php, curl, google-analytics

Can someone tell me, I'm using curl in other ways on this machine, so I know it works, but it's just loaded as a php extension, and the dll is called php_curl.dll
Is curl so much more? I can see it can me downloaded multiple places, and I'm wondering if my problem is that I'm missing some curl installation.

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28366402/failed-to-connect-to-www-googleapis-com-port-443-network-unreachable), but I'm not that familiar with curl

---

My trouble story

I'm trying to connect to Google Analytics Reporting V4

I've been following this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-php) (Earlier I've used V3 on another server).

I've been informed it had some trouble in the docs right now (whitch I've experienced as well) therefor I've used the google-api-2-client as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33483326/how-do-i-use-composer-to-setup-google-api-php-client).

It got me further, but the newest problem is throwing me of...

I get this Message:

> "Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException: cURL error 7: Failed to connect to www.googleapis.com port 443: Connection refused (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) in D:\www\rest\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php:186 Stack trace: #0 D:\www\rest\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php(150): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::createRejection(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle), Array) #1 D:\www\rest\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php(103): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::finishError(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory)) #2 D:\www\rest\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlHandler.php(43): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::finish(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory)) #3 D:\www\rest\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\Proxy.php(28): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler->__invoke(Object(G in D:\www\rest\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php on line 186"

Comment: Sounds like something odd is going on on your server. Doesn't appear to be a PHP issue, and potentially not even a cURL issue.

Comment: similar problem here cURL error 6: name lookup timed out (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

dns works properly..
curl -I https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts                                                                                                  (dev)
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Vary: X-Origin
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="https://accounts.google.com/"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the firewall blocks outward connections on port 443 (HTTPS).